# Stopping an thread application in C# Windows Application?

Tags: c#, windows

I am making  a windows application in c# in which on button click i have written some code as

```
public void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
              while(true)
               {
                    //some processing
               }
        }
```

when i starts application it running continuously.
But on other button i want to stop that application. But i am not getting how to do it?Please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "stop that application"? Are you *actually* launching another application, or do you mean "stop the code running within the event handler"? Your title mentions threads, but there's no indication that you're starting a new thread - it sounds like you're doing everything in the UI thread :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a responsive UI, you should never write code like `while (true) {...}` because thus you get the main thread busy. Here you really should use [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx). Don't forget to set its [WorkerSupportsCancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.workersupportscancellation.aspx) property before you start worker thread via [RunWorkerAsync()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkerasync.aspx). [There is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hybbz6ke.aspx) a nice how-to.

Answer (score 1):

You can make user of timer of C# here is one example of the stopwatch using timer : [Creating a simple Stopwatch/Timer application with C# / Windows Forms](http://markashleybell.com/creating-a-simple-stopwatchtimer-application-with-c-windows-forms.html)

here is one example : Check full answer and code at :  [C# start /Stop Button](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/csharplanguage/thread/f0856a56-4f71-4b9e-9b07-38bd4e66b06b)

example with using BackGroundWorker (its a bit changed version of AmaL`s code snipet):

```
BackgroundWorker bgw;
Stopwatch watch;

public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  label1.Text = "";
  watch = new Stopwatch();
  bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
  bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bgw_DoWork);
  bgw.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(bgw_ProgressChanged);
  bgw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
  bgw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
}

private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
  while (true)
  {
    bgw.ReportProgress(0);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);

    if (!watch.IsRunning)
      break;
  }
}

private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
  TimeSpan ts = watch.Elapsed;
  label1.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}", ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  watch.Start();
  bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  watch.Stop();
  watch.Reset();
  bgw.CancelAsync();      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `Background Worker` its very easy to do threading :)

Answer (score 0):

you should do the heavy working in a another thread other than in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

look here : http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mgold/multithreadingintro10062005000439am/multithreadingintro.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking your main thread when doing that while(true).

Run your heavy work in another thread instead.

You can find a threading tutorial here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645740(v=vs.71).aspx